# For a TSQL insert/update trigger, can inserted and deleted both be empty?

Tags: t-sql, triggers

I have been using a TSQL trigger under the assumption that the inserted table always contains records for an insert or update and the deleted table always contains records for updates (I am ignoring deletes).

Here is the related MSDN article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx

However, I have encountered situations where both inserted and deleted are empty. Here is a test trigger I have been using.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[InsertUpdateTest] ON [dbo].[Test] 
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
AS
    DECLARE @countInserted INT
    DECLARE @countDelete INT

    SET @countInsert = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INSERTED)
    SET @countDeleted = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DELETED)

    IF (@countInserted = 0 AND @countDelete = 0)
    BEGIN
        print 'Inserted and deleted are both empty'
    END
```

Under what conditions does this occur?

Comment: +1 In reality, has this ever been a problem for you? Surely if there are no rows in `inserted` or `deleted`, whatever action you're hoping to perform in this trigger won't affect any rows either and so won't be computationally expensive.

Comment: @Bridge - Normally, yes, but I am still interested to know why the trigger even fires under these conditions. I also found that the UPDATE() function, which can used to test for column changes, returns true when inserted and deleted are empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering my own question. This occurs when an update statement on the triggered table doesn't update any rows. The trigger still fires but with empty inserted and deleted tables. For example:

```
UPDATE Test Set somefield=0 WHERE id='Values does not exist'
```